# Printing in JSF2.0

Tags: jquery, jsf-2

I am using JSF 2.0 and Jquery , I want to print one panel group in stead of whole page when ever user clicks on Print button but the page shouldn't be refreshed why because after loading the page i am invalidating the session.
In the page i am showing the refrence number and contact us.
Can any one help me in this scenario.

Regards

Comment: Try with the printer Primefaces component : http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/printer.jsf

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your quick reply we are not using primefaces.only in JSF or jquery

Comment: Use the same template and use render attribute to show only the element which interest you for the print. jQuery seems to have a lot of plugins for printing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just supply a CSS file with `media="print"`.

```
<h:outputStylesheet name="print.css" media="print" />
```

*(which will effectively generate the following in HTML `<head>`)*

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/contextname/resources/print.css" media="print" />
```

In the `print.css` file itself, just hide all elements you'd like to hide from the print by setting the `display` property to `none`. E.g.

```css
#header, #menu, #footer, #title {
    display: none;
}
```

In case of the following JSF markup example, only the desired panel group would be printed.

```
<div id="header">...</div>
<div id="menu">...</div>
<div id="content">
    <h2 id="title">...</h2>
    <h:panelGroup>...</h:panelGroup>     <!-- Only this one will be printed. -->
</div>
<div id="footer">...</div>
```

#### See also:

- [CSS media types](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html)